# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String

Tags: c#, exception, handler, request.querystring, nul

Please take a look at the following code. It's in `handler.asxh`.

```cs
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    new RequestManagementFacade().PinRequest(Int32.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["requestId"]), (Boolean.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["isPinned"])));
}
```

This is showing the following error:

```sh
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String
```

There is value being passed as I have checked the context request query string, however, the code breaks at this stage.

This handler will connect to the business logic layer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: Surely requestId or isPinned is null, evaluate them both and trap some errors!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is value being passed as i have checke dthe context request query string

I strongly suspect your diagnostics are incorrect then. Values don't magically go missing - you need to question your assumptions. This is easy to debug through though. I would suggest changing your code to:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    string requestId = context.Request.QueryString["requestId"];
    string isPinned = context.Request.QueryString["isPinned"];
    var facade = new RequestManagementFacade();
    facade.PinRequest(Int32.Parse(requestId), Boolean.Parse(isPinned));
}
```

It's then *really* simple to step through and find out what's going on.

Comment: And it's even simpler if you put the parsing code on separate lines also: int ID = Int32.Parse(requestId);   And for even more robustness, you could use TryParse and automatically handle errors.

Comment: @SteveWellens: Well, if the problem is that either `requestId` or `isPinned` is null, that should be clear before the parse calls.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's why I suggested TryParse....it handles null values as well as invalid string values.

Comment: @SteveWellens: `TryParse` is only appropriate when it's *expected* to be potentially invalid though. It sounds like the OP really expects it to be valid by now, and an exception is an entirely reasonable response. It's unclear.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that either `context.Request.QueryString["requestId"]` or `context.Request.QueryString["isPinned"]` is not returning a valid string value. Check that both values are passed in the query string with the proper IDs, those being of course `requestId` and `isPinned`.

Comment: Okay solved when passing the values to the handler i inserted it as 

    "PinRequest.ashx?="+requestId+isPinned"

Which gave me the result 2True

So i realised the hiccup was with not including the string names 

    "PinRequest.ashx?requestId=" + this._requestId + "&isPinned=" + this._isPinned

Thanks for you help guys 

LeviBotelho Thank you made me check something i was missing out when checking as its javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Okay solved when passing the values to the handler i inserted it as

```
"PinRequest.ashx?="+requestId+isPinned"
```

Which gave me the result 2True

So i realised the hiccup was with not including the string names

```
"PinRequest.ashx?requestId=" + this._requestId + "&isPinned=" + this._isPinned
```

Thanks for you help guys

LeviBotelho Thank you made me check something i was missing out when checking as its javascript

Answer (score 0):

experienced the error while using `Int32.Parse(myString)` to convert string to int and afterwards assign the value to an object's attribute. Using another method for converting(`Convert.ToInt32(myString)`) string to int worked for me.